# Geolocation with google geolocation api

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

So, i have this website and i need to geolocate the position of the visitor.

I saw this code at google code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gears_init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');

function updatePosition(position) {
  alert('Current lat/lon is: ' + position.latitude + ',' + position.longitude);
}

function handleError(positionError) {
  alert('Attempt to get location failed: ' + positionError.message);
}

geo.getCurrentPosition(updatePosition, handleError);
</script>
```

Seems pretty much what i need but i must know if the visitor is near City X or if it's closer to City Y

Any way i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you find the user's position, you need to do a reverse geolocation (see [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding)). Then you can use the "city" field of the returned result to see where google puts this user.
If you would take a suggestion, you can also implement visitor's geolocation through HTML5's navigator.geolocation object, and with this you will also serve visitors that use other browsers that don't have google gears installed.

Comment: the problem with HTML5 is that a request is popped up for user to allow geolocation, if the user doesn't agree in giving his current location, it ruins the purpose of having geolocation. 

How those banners that sometimes show my city or a city near me? Is it with IP location?

Comment: I thought google gears would demand the user's permission as well (it's very invasive that it doesn't). If you want ip-based geolocation, you need another service (google doesn't provide this). Check http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity for example. Note that there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

Once you grab a latitude longitude pair for your visitor, to find which city they are closest to, you may want to implement a search of haversine distance combined with lat long of all cities. You can find lat long info for most cities from geonames: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ and more info on haversine distance is here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula